# How to install Ubuntu server with basic VGA only instead of loading graphics card driver

Tags: graphics, vga

I have an Intel DN2800MT motherboard with a graphics card that isn't well supported.  I'm able to completely install Ubuntu server on the machine, but when it boots after install I get a kernel panic, presumably because the graphic driver is tanking.

How do I tell the installer (or Grub for that matter) /not/ to load any graphics drivers?  I don't care if I'm stuck with 80x25 basic VGA, the machine is a server and I'll only be accessing it from SSH.

I've probably installed Ubuntu a hundred times on various machines and am reasonably confident with the command line.

Many thanks!

Comment: Try to remove "quiet splash" from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT option in `/etc/default/grub` then run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: I would delegate you to https://askubuntu.com/questions/344903/install-on-a-laptop-with-external-monitor-only ; there is a grub option (command?) that seems relevant

Answer (score 0):

Turn it off, remove your graphics card, plug the VGA into the Motherboard directly, and turn it back on.

Comment: The DN2800MT is a low-power Atom motherboard that has an onboard graphics card -- this is the one giving problems.  It's a server so I can't/won't be installing another card, so unfortunately this won't work.  I appreciate your answer, though.