# getting laptop boot screen on external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have my Ubuntu Desktop (13.04) installation setup for dual monitors (one VGA and one HDMI, built-in display off) out of my laptop. This is working fine when I am logged in, however when I reboot the boot/login screen is only on my laptop screen. Since I want to have the laptop close and tucked away, this is a problem.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work properly? I tried a suggestion of adding a file to `/etc/X11/Xsession`. I called it '98extmonitor' and it had the following contents:

```
xrandr -q | grep 'VGA1 connected' && xrandr --output LVDS1 --off --output VGA1 --auto
```

But that had no change in effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by adding an option to the GRUB command line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=LVDS-1:d video=VGA-1:e video=HDMI-1:e"
```

That boots up my system with the same login on both monitors. When I login, the dual spanning monitor setup kicks in.

Comment: How can I find those parameters you provided? Are they identical systems to sytems?